# Pytorch:DataParallel can't reduce model inference time with same total batch size iamges

Tags: pytorch

When I use `torch.nn.DataParallel()` to realize data parallel computation, I find the parallel model inference time for the same total amount batch size don't significantly decrease compared with serial model.

As shown below.

```
model = SNModel()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
if parallel_enable:
    model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=gpu_ids) # gpu_ids = [0,1,2,3] total 4 gpus
model.to(args.device)
criterion.to(args.device)
```

calculate 100 iteration model inference time:

```
torch.cuda.synchronize()
st = time.time()
outputs, loss = model(images, path, labels, criterion, gpu_nums)
torch.cuda.synchronize()
total_tm += time.time() - st
```

With single gpu:

```
100 iter model time  23s (around)
```

With 4 gpus:

```
100 iter model time  103s (around)
```

There is only `103 - 23*4  = 11s` reduced.

Is there any wrong? Hope you can help me! I have been troubled by this for a long time. I know that there is something wrong that I didn't find out. This phenomenon has appeared in other models, so that I have always abandoned the use of parallelism.